# Trying to make invisible forward and back buttons for image slideshow

Tags: html, css, image, button, slideshow

Screenshot of how I want slideshow buttons to function:

[image: screenshot of how I want slideshow buttons to function]

I am trying to create forward and back buttons for my slideshow that are invisible and span past the image to the edge of the page. However I cannot figure out how to do it.

I tried to use flexbox with the parent element being the image container and the children being the buttons. However, everytime I plugged in these properties the buttons disappeared and i could not click on or find the buttons anymore.

Here is my html:

```
<!-- Slideshow container -->
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="img/3.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="img/30.JPG" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="img/39.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>

  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <div class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)"></div>
  <div class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)"></div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
* {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 30%;
  max-height: 30%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20vh;
  margin-bottom: 20vh;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  flex: 1;
  user-select: none;
}
```

Here is my JS:

```
let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

Comment: You seem to use a class `dot` in your JS that isn't used in your HTML.

Comment: Hey thank you that was helpful, only thing is how would I expand the buttons to go past the image to stretch the rest of the page. Should I put more padding in the slideshow container?

Answer (score 1):

you just need to use `mySlides` class instead of `dot` in JS dots variable.
And there are some corrections in css which are as mentioned below:

please refer this link for live demo to understand in details.
https://jsfiddle.net/76L4phfc/

```
.prev,
.next {
    background: red;
    opacity: 0.2;
    z-index: 55555;
    width: 48%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
.next { right: 0;}
.prev { left: 0;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    /* Slideshow container */
    
    .slideshow-container {
      max-width: 30%;
      max-height: 30%;
      position: relative;
      margin: auto;
      margin-top: 20vh;
      margin-bottom: 20vh;
      justify-content: space-between;
      display: flex;
    }
    /* Hide the images by default */
    
    .mySlides {
      display: none;
    }
    /* Next & previous buttons */
    
    .prev,
    .next {
      cursor: pointer;
      flex: 1;
      user-select: none;
      background: red;
      opacity: 0.2;
      z-index: 55555;
      width: 48%;
      height: 100%;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
    }
    
    .next {
      right: 0;
    }
    
    .prev {
      left: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Slideshow container -->
  <div class="slideshow-container">
    <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/mEZ3PoFGs_k" style="width: 100%" />
      <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/X-Z9gHq6iow" style="width: 100%" />
      <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/mEZ3PoFGs_k" style="width: 100%" />
      <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/X-Z9gHq6iow" style="width: 100%" />
      <div class="text">Caption Four</div>
    </div>

    <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
    <div class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)"></div>
    <div class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)"></div>
  </div>

  <script>
    let slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    // Next/previous controls
    function plusSlides(n) {
      showSlides((slideIndex += n));
    }

    // Thumbnail image controls
    function currentSlide(n) {
      showSlides((slideIndex = n));
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
      let i;
      let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1;
      }
      if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length;
      }
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
      dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey thank you that was helpful, only thing is how would I expand the buttons to go past the image to stretch the rest of the page. Should I put more padding in the slideshow container?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `position: absolute;` for the buttons, and I made a example as follows:

```js
let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
    * {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 30%;
  max-height: 30%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20vh;
  margin-bottom: 20vh;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}


/* Next and previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 49%;
  height: 100%;
}

.prev {
  left: 0;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
}

/* Hide button elements by default */
.prev, .next {
  opacity: 0.3;
  background-color: gray;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

/* Show button elements on hover */
.slideshow-container .prev:hover, .slideshow-container .next:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!-- Slideshow container -->
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="img/3.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="img/30.JPG" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="img/39.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>

  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
</div>
<div class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)"></div>
<div class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)"></div>
```

I think that’s what you want, but a reminder for you, dots in your JS code seem unnecessary, and it will cause an error. I recommend you delete these codes.

Comment: Hey thank you that was helpful, only thing is how would I expand the buttons to go past the image to stretch the rest of the page. Should I put more padding in the slideshow container?

Comment: You just have to put the div of buttons out of the container. I've edited my answers, check it out.